# I am trying to download facebook profile picture using java.But getting error

Tags: java, facebook

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;

public class SaveImageFromUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // proxy settings
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "porxyHost");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
             public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return (new PasswordAuthentication("userxyz","password".toCharArray()));
            }
        };
        Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

        String imageUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/10000012233xxxx/picture";
        String destinationFile = "D://image4.jpg";

        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
    }

    public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

}
```

My code works fine and downloads image for other imageurl paths.But it is not working when I use String imageUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/10000012233xxxx/picture";

I am getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at SaveImageFromUrl.saveImage(SaveImageFromUrl.java:33)
    at SaveImageFromUrl.main(SaveImageFromUrl.java:28)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that your application can follow redirects, because Facebook is sending one if you request

```
/{user_id}/picture
```

To implement this, have a look at http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

Also, try setting the Proxy authentication like this:

```
System.setProperty( "http.proxyUserName", "username" );
System.setProperty( "http.proxyPassword", "password" );
```

I suspect you get the timeout from your proxy connection, but you should be able to test this yourself.

Comment: How to do that redirection?

Comment: Google is your friend my friend...! I updated my answer.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/ IS NOT WORKING

Comment: Plz look into this one

Comment: I refered link  http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/ and tried to do redirect as u suggest.But still its giving me same error - CONNECTION TIME OUT

Comment: Updated my answer. Check that the timeout is not from your proxy!

Comment: NO ITS NOT FROM MY PROXY

Comment: THEN I DON'T KNOW! I guess you need to put in some effort yourself and test it one by one. I'm out.

Comment: Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055669/how-to-download-image-from-facebook-graph-api/23056175#23056175

Comment: This post was to get the picture url after the redirect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057329/how-to-get-redirected-url-and-content-using-httpurlconnection