# Error in loading facebook profile pic to android

Tags: android, facebook, profile

my code..

```
     ImageView userpicture;
     userpicture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userImage);
     URL img_value = null;
      try {
        img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
    try {
    mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     userpicture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

And log cat error.......

```
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.avion.ryb/com.avion.ryb.slidingmenu.FaceBookLogin}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at com.avion.ryb.slidingmenu.FaceBookLogin.onCreate(FaceBookLogin.java:71)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5117)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
05-12 15:42:11.728: E/AndroidRuntime(21176):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You'r performing your network UI related operation on main thread. But you can't do this. So you need to use `AsyncTask` or `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your application can handle redirects in a proper way. See my answer at [How to download image from facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055669/how-to-download-image-from-facebook-graph-api/23056175#23056175) and the Facebook docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/picture