# Facebook Profile Pic (Facebook Android SDK)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am stuck on how to retrieve the profile pic from this requests response. This code was provided in the GraphAPI documentation.

```
        Session session = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession();

    /* make the API call */
    new Request(
        session,
        "/me/picture",
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                /* handle the result */

            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();
```

**What should I be looking to do to retrieve the picture from the response?**

Comment: I am not exactly sure do you need to use Graph API to retrieve profile picture for a user. Once you have user id, it should be possible to use url http://graph.facebook.com/123/picture , where 123 is user id or username, to load profile picture. And if you want to use Graph API, you might need to use _fields_ parameter, i.e http://graph.facebook.com/123?fields=picture .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer at [How to download image from facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055669/how-to-download-image-from-facebook-graph-api/23056175#23056175) I guess you're facing a redirection problem...